# Intercambiar credenciales por ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Revisando codigo de un sitio mio que había realizado hace mucho tiempo (y que no esta activo) vi que para redirigirme a otro sitio web pasaba las credenciales de esta forma:

```
protected void Redig(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://sitioprueba.local?usuario=" + idusuario + "&pass=" + pass);
        }
```

Me entro la duda si esto podría traer algun problema de seguridad. Revise la URL que se muestra y quize buscar mas información con las DevTools pero no parece mostrarse el usuario y contraseña a simple vista. Esta bien realizar esto de esta forma?
Uso ASP.NET con Web Forms.

Comment: Como puedes ver es muy inseguro, lo mejor es que se genere un token y te redirijas al nuevo sitio con el este nuevo token debe ser validado por el servidor y generar otro nuevo para la sesion actual en ese sitio.

Comment: Claro, eso suponía porque ahora mantengo las sesiones por JTW pero quería sacarme la duda si ASP.NET ya realizaba algo para mejorar la seguridad.

Comment: ASP.net tiene muchas cosas para mantener la seguridad, el problema : a los desarrolladores promedio les hace falta buscarlas. Revisa la documentación bro, existe una apartado exclusivo de seguridad :D